# c++ How do I fix my no instance error on my setMaterial piece of code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I just started coding with C++, and am doing a few tutorials on using C++, but when I finished up one part of code I saw that it was erroring:

> no instance of overload function "Unigine::ObjectMeshDynamic""setMaterial" matches the argument

Here is my code, and even though I did exactly as I was supposed to, maybe there was something I missed, even after looking at it over and over again (this is in unigine):

```
int AppWorldLogic::addMeshToScene(const char *file_name, const char *mesh_name, const char *material_name, Math::Vec3 position)
{
    MeshPtr mesh = Mesh::create();
    ObjectMeshDynamicPtr omd;
    if (file_name)
    {
        if (!mesh->load(file_name))
        {
            Log::error("\nError opening .mesh file!\n");
            mesh.clear();
            return 0;
        }
        else omd = ObjectMeshDynamic::create(mesh);
    }
    else
    {
        mesh->addBoxSurface("box_surface", Math::vec3(0.5f));
        omd = ObjectMeshDynamic::create(mesh);
    }

    // setting node material, name and position
    omd->setMaterial(material_name, "*");
    omd->setName(mesh_name);
    omd->setWorldPosition(position);

    Objects.append(omd);

    Log::message("-> Object %s added to the scene. \n", mesh_name);

    mesh.clear();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What do your ```setMaterial``` definitions look like?

Comment: Hello and welcome. May I recommend taking the [tour] and reading [ask]? You will learn how to compose your questions to improve the odds of having a pleasant Stack Overflow user experience.

Comment: does this work to answer the definitions  question @ewong                                                                                                                                  
 private:
 //auxiliary functions
 int addMeshToScene(const char *file_name, const char *mesh_name, const char *material_name, Math::Vec3 position);
 int initObjects();

 // scene objects vector
 Vector<ObjectMeshDynamicPtr> Objects;

Comment: You can edit the question to add the missing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read Unigine's *current* (2.15.1) documentation for [`setMaterial()`](https://developer.unigine.com/en/docs/2.15.1/api/library/objects/class.object#setMaterial_Material_int_void) (which [`Unigine::ObjectMeshDynamic`](https://developer.unigine.com/en/docs/2.15.1/api/library/objects/class.objectmeshdynamic) inherits from [`Unigine::Object`](https://developer.unigine.com/en/docs/2.15.1/api/library/objects/class.object)), you will see that it is overloaded to accept only the following parameters:

```
void setMaterial ( const Ptr<Material> & mat, int surface )
void setMaterial ( const Ptr<Material> & mat, const char * pattern )
```

You are trying to call `SetMaterial()` with 2 strings as input, and there is no such overload available, hence the error.

`"*"` is a string literal, which is implemented as a `const char[2]` array that decays into a `const char*`.  So you can safely pass that to the `pattern` parameter.

However, you are trying to pass your `material_name` variable, which is a `const char*` string, to the `mat` parameter. A `const char*` is not compatible with `Ptr<Material>`. `setMaterial()` wants a pointer to a [`Unigine::Material`](https://developer.unigine.com/en/docs/2.15.1/api/library/rendering/class.material) object instead of a string.

I looked at *earlier* versions of the documentation, and found that prior to 2.15, there were additional overloads of `setMaterial()`, some of which accepted a `const char* name` parameter instead of a `const Ptr<Material> &mat` parameter.  It seems those overloads where removed in 2.15.  Which means the code you are trying to use was meant for an earlier version of Unigine, not for the latest version.

It appears that you copied your code from [this documentation page](https://developer.unigine.com/en/docs/2.15.1/start/programmer/nodes), which has apparently not been updated to account for the latest Unigine version. There is obviously now another step involved to get a `Material` object from a name string in the latest version.  For instance, by calling [`Materials::findMaterial()`](https://developer.unigine.com/en/docs/2.15.1/api/library/rendering/class.materials#findManualMaterial_cstr_Material).  Or alternatively, using [`setMaterialPath()`](https://developer.unigine.com/en/docs/2.15.1/api/library/objects/class.object?rlang=cpp#setMaterialPath_cstr_int_void) instead of `setMaterial()`.

Have a look at the [Upgrading to UNIGINE 2.15: API Migration: Materials Changes](https://developer.unigine.com/en/docs/2.15/upgrade/migration_api#materials_changes) documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I understand this a lot better and why I am getting the error but I don't understand how it worked for them.  Because they also used the material_name which was a const char* do you know what could have changed for them?

Comment: "*I don't understand how it worked for them*" - Who says it does? This is obviously an error in the documentation. You are trying to call `setMaterial()` with 2 strings as input, but there is no such overload available, hence the error. If you want to know the correct code you should use, I suggest you contact the Unigine team directly, so they can fix the mistake.

Comment: I say I don't understand how it worked for them because they ran it without any problems https://youtu.be/w7JGHRxAZWw here is a link if you wanna see what I mean but ima take the suggestion and I might contact them directly thank you.

Comment: @Karmawillgetchew At position 4:59 in that video, when they begin typing in the parameters for the `setMatrial()` call, you can see that Code Completion finds **6 overloads** of `setMaterial()`, but the documentation only shows **2 overloads**. However, the Code Completion also shows the `material_name` being passed to a `Ptr<Material>` parameter, not to a `const char*` parameter, but there is no *documented* constructor of `Ptr` or `Material` that accepts a `const char*`. So, clearly the person recording that video is using a different version of Unigine than you are using.

Comment: That actually would explain so much I had suspicion that it was the versions and stuff but now you confirmed it thank you for all you have done and sorry if I annoyed you a bit.

Comment: @Karmawillgetchew that video is over 2 years old, and it turns out that earlier versions of Unigine did accept a `const char*` material name in `setMaterial()`, but that was apparently removed in the latest version.

Comment: ya I guess I should have looked farther into it then started coding but instead I guess I just didn't think about that.